# MongoDB update all fields of array error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Im tring to set 0 the items.qty of a document obtains by a id query.

```
db.warehouses.update(
    // query 
    {
        _id:ObjectId('5322f07e139cdd7e31178b78')
    },    
    // update 
    {
        $set:{"items.$.qty":0}
    },    
    // options 
    {
        "multi" : true,  // update only one document 
        "upsert" : true  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query 
    }
);
```

Return:

Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.

This is the document that i want to set all items.qty to 0

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid" : "5322f07e139cdd7e31178b78" },
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": { "$oid" : "531ed4cae604d3d30df8e2ca" },
      "brand": "BJFE",
      "color": "GDRNCCD",
      "hand": 1,
      "model": 0,
      "price": 500,
      "qty": 0,
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "brand": "BJFE",
      "color": "GDRNCCD",
      "hand": 1,
      "id": "23",
      "model": 0,
      "price": 500,
      "qty": 4,
      "type": 0
    },
    {
      "brand": "BJFE",
      "color": "GDRNCCD",
      "hand": 1,
      "id": "3344",
      "model": 0,
      "price": 500,
      "qty": 6,
      "type": 0
    }
  ],
  "name": "a"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### EDIT

The detail missing from the question was that the required field to update was actually in a *sub-document*. This changes the answer considerably:

---

This is a constraint of what you can **possibly** do with updating array elements. And this is clearly explained in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). Mostly in this paragraph:

> The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the **first** element that matches the query document

So here is the thing. Trying to update **all** of the array elements in a single statement like this will **not** work. In order to do this you must to the following.

```js
db.warehouses.find({ "items.qty": { "$gt": 0 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.items.forEach(function(item) {
        item.qty = 0;
    });
    db.warehouses.update({ "_id": doc._id }, doc );
})
```

Which is basically the way to update **every** array element.

The **multi** setting in `.update()` means across multiple "documents". It **cannot** be applied to multiple elements of an array. So presently the best option is to replace the whole thing. Or in this case we may just as well replace the **whole** document since we need to do that anyway.

For **real** bulk data, use [**db.eval()**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/). But **please read** the documentation first:

```js
db.eval(function() {
    db.warehouses.find({ "items.qty": { "$gt": 0 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
        doc.items.forEach(function(item) {
            item.qty = 0;
        });
        db.warehouses.update({ "_id": doc._id }, doc );
    });
})
```

Updating **all** the elements in an array across the **whole** collection is not simple.

---

### Original

---

Pretty much exactly what the error says. In order to use a positional operator you need to **match** something first. As in:

```js
db.warehouses.update(
    // query 
    {
        _id:ObjectId('5322f07e139cdd7e31178b78'),
        "items.qty": { "$gt": 0 }
    },    
    // update 
    {
        $set:{"items.$.qty":0}
    },    
    // options 
    {
        "multi" : true,  
        "upsert" : true  
    }
);
```

So where the **match** condition fins the **position** of the items that are *less than* 0 then that **index** is passed to the positional operator.

*P.S* : When **muti** is *true* it means it updates **every** document. Leave it `false` if you only mean **one**. Which is the default.

Comment: Not works OK, this inly update the first item with qty>0..I need to update all, i set multi to true but dotn work.

Comment: @colymore I think you should remove the `upsert: true` for starters since you are not intending to **insert** new records. The **multi** works as intended. The comment I gave was because you have the `ObjectId` in your **match** criteria. That implies **one** item. Remove that and keep **multi** as **true** when you want to update **everything**.

Comment: I edit the question with a document example, that i want is set all qty in document.items array to 0..But only update the first item with qty 0..

Comment: @colymore Give me 5 minutes then refresh. This is not the only time I have seen you post a question in this manner. You need to understand what **sub-documents** are. Until now your question has been misleading.

Comment: all the documents that i found are in english, and its very difficult for me read and understant them, and i try with code by try-error..I will read more of subdocuments in mongoDB.Thanks

Comment: @colymore The problem I have found here and in other questions is that you do not specify **exactly** what you want. I appreciate that english is an issue. But please try and be more accurate to your requirements. See the edits to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now i understand lot of thinks..:D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [$ positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) only when you specify an array in the first argument (i.e., the query part used to identify the document you want to update).

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array field to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you because you have been giving **good** answers. As help, try to use the `>` to mark "block quotes" when quoting from documentation. A good guide is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Keep up the work. You clearly understand enough to help others considerably.

Comment: Thank you, Neil. I hadn't read the guide.  I will review it completely before I post again.

Comment: No problem. Look up "tagging" in the page as well. I only saw this because I was on the page already.