# Best way to get around bug #1243 in MongoDB (Use positional operator to update all items in an array)

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am writing a database layer where 1:n records are cached in a _children field.
So, if you have people:

```
{   
  id: 1,
  name: 'Tony',
  surname: 'Mobily',
  _children: {
    addresses: [],
  }
},
{
  name: 'Chiara',
  surname: 'Mobily',
  _children: {
    addresses: [],
  }
}
```

And then add a record to addresses:

```
{
  id: 100
  personId: 1,
  street: 'Some street',
  country: 'Australia',
}

{
  id: 101
  personId: 1,
  street: 'Some other street',
  country: 'Australia',
}
```

The right record is updated automatically in People:

```
{   
  id: 1,
  name: 'Tony',
  surname: 'Mobily',
  _children: {
    addresses: [
      {
        id: 100
        personId: 1,
        street: 'Some street',
        country: 'Australia',
      },

      {
        id: 101
        personId: 1,
        street: 'Some other street',
        country: 'Australia',
      }

    ],
  }
},
```

My layer also stores UPPERCASE versions of all text fields, and automatically runs case-insensitive searches etc. It also deals with "lookup" fields, populating them automatically.

When you do a mass update on an Address field, it also runs the update on the "parent" fields, so that everything is in sync. It all works beautifully.

Except, when you try and do a MASS update of the Address table.

For example:

```
addresses.update( { country: 'Australia' }, { street: 'Something else' }, { multi: true } )
```

When this is done, I also run a query for each "parent" table (in this case, `people`) this way:

```
people.update( { _children.country: 'Australia'}, { '_children.addresses.$.street': 'Something else' }, { multi: true } )
```

Note that the "new" query is automatically worked out.

However, because of bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243, I am basically screwed.

(Note that inserting is always a single operation that implies a simple $push (no problems there), and deleting is an operation that requires a $pull on _children ($pull accepts a filter to work on the array. So, no problems there too). The only problem is only with mass-update.)

Now:

- I cannot load the full document and change all of the entries by hand for several reasons: (1) performance: I would need to run an update on every single record matching, and it could be 1 million; (2) AND it's actually impossible because I wouldn't have a way to "re-run" the query (which might involve regexps etc.) on the loaded document
- I cannot repeat the update operation till I get ZERO updates (they have all been changed) because if the change is such that will *also* match, it will do it forever (if you change 'perth' to 'perth2', and match for anything beginning with 'p').

But, I really need this feature and I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Do you guys have some ideas, other than beg the MongoDB guys to fix this issue, which is yet another weakness in Mongo's array updating?

Comment: Failing, any way to change a schema to suit though. The only way it to replace the whole array. You could look at the `db.eval()` form of processing the documents as was shown in an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22405555/2313887). But no. There is no other way to update all elements of an array otherwise.

Comment: Can I change the whole array _atomically_ using `db.eval()`? Plus, if I were to replace the whole array, I still wouldn't be able to do it "following the query" so to speak... right? (or, I would need to reapply my mongo filter using Javascript...) (I tried with $elemMatch as well: same problem, same results...)

Comment: Sorry, AFK for a while. I hope the example below clears up the usage of this. And apologies for the earlier misread of what you were asking for.

Comment: No worries mate... Greetings from Perth :)

Comment: please note this is not a bug as the feature never existed in MongoDB - this is a request for a new feature.

Comment: is this in fact a "one off" operation? i.e. something that can be done as a "maintenance" type task?  Or do you expect to need this type of functionality frequently - in which case a schema change is definitely called for.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky The disussion that happened some time ago now confirmed this **was** one off maintenance. And from your *recent* comments which is why **warnings** were given. But this is a "sharded" cluster in reality, so without doing maintenance on a "un-sharded" collection and replacing then the option was chosen to live with client/server transfer and the required multiple updates.

Comment: A missing feature that cripples a piece of software is a bug in my books. Nearly as bad as mongo issue 831... This is not at all a one off operation. This is to Develop https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer/blob/master/README.md#automatic-loading-of-children-joins -- I implemented a way to load children records instantaneously by keeping a list of children records in the record itself as an array under _children.  but I have no way to update the children in case a parent record has a mass update. Its for a library, not possible to "change the schema". At the moment I throw...

Comment: @asyakamsky prev comment was for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So considering you are "Bulk Updating" and that this is likely a one off operation, you may consider using [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) like this:

```js
db.eval(function() {
    db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
        doc._children.forEach(function(item) {
            item.ucCountry = item.country.toUpperCase;
        });
        db.collection.update(
            { "_id": doc._id },
            { "$set": { "_children": doc._children } }
        );
    });
})
```

So it's pretty much the standard loop, but this time it runs on the server. You can even add the $set operation for just the array element being changed to save a little more overhead.

Be warned though to **read** the documentation. You will be **locking** the database for writes, and **blocking** all other JavaScript operations such as "mapReduce" during the time that the update is performed. But it is the fastest way to do this.

Comment: This looked promising till I realised that I am using mongodb as a service, and I doubt eval() is an option :( looks like I am well stuck! I might just throw when somebody uses my layer to do mass updates on a table that is 1:n child of another. But... It sucks. Mongo really rocks for my use case... Oh well.

Comment: @Merc Which service provider? I would doubt that you cannot do it. Which is exactly what makes it useful. What the function (from your client or driver) does is sends that "JavaScript" argument to the server. That packaged code gets executed on the server internally. Unless you are using a REST API from your application (and don't do that unless you have legacy code) and you are actually using a native driver, then yes it will be supported. I don't know of a way that API calls can be locked in this way. I could be wrong. But you should check. + Don't wait for a different answer.

Comment: @actually. Here's the test. Connect your mongo shell to the hosted database. In the shell type this: `db.eval(function(){ return "Hello" })`. If you don't get an error and get the response, then it works. Otherwise check permissions to see if it can be enabled. BTW, Invoked from drivers, the argument containing the JavaScript is actually a string.

Comment: `db.eval(function(){ return "Hello" })
Sat Mar 15 19:50:02.301 { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:571` as I feared, no db.eval available. Ugh...

Comment: @Merc Do you mind offering the provider? I don't mind trawling their docs with you right now. A few minutes to spare.

Comment: @Merc and assuming there is some analog to the standard roles permissions. See [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#combined-access)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I wrote it. It's MongoLab. But, eval is not available on sharded databases, it only should be used for admin purposes, and it would require a lot of work on my layer. I think I will just `throw()` till they fix #1243, it really does seem to be my only option if I want to stay sane and ship something within the year...

Comment: db.eval is not available for a good reason - it should not be used for anything.  it's bad for performance, and since it'll run Javascript you may as well do whatever it would do in the application.