# $set properties for all nested documents

Tags: mongodb

I would like to know how to set properties for all nested documents.

Suppose I have a `category` document that has nested `item` documents:

```
{
  items: [
    {
      hidden: true
    },
    {
      hidden: true
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

How can I update all the `hidden` property of items to `false`?

I have tried this:

```
db.categories.update({}, {$set: {'items.$.hidden': false}})
```

But MongoDB gives me `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: items.$.hidden`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update using script due to [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243)

Use following to update all fields:

```
db.collection.find({
    _id: ObjectId("558bbd23fdf0f33ec7a067c8")
}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.items.forEach(function(items) {
    if (items.hidden == true) {
        items.hidden = false;
    }
    });
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: Why is `db.collection.save(doc);` necessary?

Comment: @MikeC In foreach function we are setting value for `hidden = false` and need to save its updated value which will be overwrite current value.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following update which uses the cursor method **[`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** to iterate the cursor and access the documents, get the `items` array and loop over it and modify the `hidden` field, as in the following example:

```
db.test.insert([
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "hidden" : true
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : 2,
                "hidden" : true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "hidden" : true
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : 2,
                "hidden" : true
            }
        ]
    }
])

db.test.find().forEach(function (doc){
    var items = [];
    doc.items.forEach(function (item){
        item.hidden = false;
        items.push(item);
    });
    doc.items = items;
    db.test.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating all the elements in an array across the whole collection is not simple. You'll have to use nested forEach.

> The positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element
>   that matches the query document

Please take a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405377/mongodb-update-all-fields-of-array-error).